# php + mysql : find data by time end & time start

Tags: php4

event table have two fields start and end and all in datetime format

This is query

```
SELECT e.* FROM jos_events e 
 WHERE 1=1
AND e.start >= 2006-07-10  
AND e.end <= 2015-10-21 
ORDER BY e.id DESC
```

i want to find events between time start and time end.
how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.* FROM jos_events e 
WHERE
   AND e.start <= '2006-07-10 00:00:00'
   AND e.end >= '2015-10-21 23:59:59'
ORDER BY e.id DESC
```